# How do I use JavaScript and Nth-Last-Child to add and remove CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I'm not a JavaScript wizard by any means, but I'm trying to figure out a way with JavaScript to add and remove classes to a series of DIVs based on the click of one button. Let is say that I have a list:

```
<div id="homepage">
 <div class="hpFeature"></div> 
 <div class="hpFeature"></div>
 <div class="hpFeature"></div>
 <div class="hpFeature"></div>
 <div class="hpFeature"></div>
</div>

<button class="featureButton">Click Here</button>
```

My default CSS for progressive enhancement purposes so there is at least one image shown as fallback:

```
.hpFeature:nth-child(1) {display:block;}
.hpFeature {display:none;}
.fide {position: absolute; left:-9999px;}
```

...and my JavaScript so far is something like this:

```
var count = $('.hpFeature').length;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hpFeature').css('display','block');
    $('.hpFeature').addClass('fide');
    $('.hpFeature:nth-child(' + count + ')').removeClass('fide');
});

$(function(){
    $(".featureButton").click(function(){
        $('.hpFeature').removeClass('fide');
    });
});
```

So, I'm trying to figure out a simple way to do this with the nth-last-child property showing the first image through JavaScript, and then scrolling through then when clicking on the button it goes to the next one in the count, removes .fide, and at the end goes back to the first (also I can't seem to get nth-last-child to work but can get nth-child to work).

Comment: Maybe $('.hpFeature:last')?

Comment: FYI, `$(document).ready(function () {...` and `$(function() {...` are doing the same thing. You can put all your code in one or the other.

Comment: Thanks @MiniRagnarok that makes it a little smoother, but I still don't know how to write JavaScript that can go to the next item in the list; I assume it will have to be an array?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would delegate the array functionality to a native javascript array.

I can then manipulate that array and have it read out as html.

So we could create an array

```
var hpFeatureArray = []
```

Create a function to bind to html

```
function refreshArray() {
  var content = '' 
  for (var i=0; i < hpFeatureArray.length; i++) content = content + '<div class="hpFeature"></div>'
  $('#homepage').html(content)
}
```

Refresh.

```
refreshArray()
```

As far as the actual manipulation of data, it's easy to use native JavaScript array manipulation now.

```
hpFeatureArray.push('whatever')
refreshArray()
```

Here's an example
http://codepen.io/ajkochanowicz/pen/spfAL/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `nth-child` and the extreme positioning in the `fide` classe, I think you can do this with simply an "active" class (to identify which is the current section) and changing the `display` value.  Something like this:

```
<div id="homepage">
    <div class="hpFeature active"></div> 
    <div class="hpFeature"></div>
    <div class="hpFeature"></div>
    <div class="hpFeature"></div>
    <div class="hpFeature"></div>
</div>

<button class="featureButton">Click Here</button>
```

. . . and replace the CSS with this:

```
.hpFeature {display:none;}
.hpFeature.active {display:block;}
```

Then, you're JS code would just need to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".featureButton").on("click", function() {
        var $activeDiv = $(".active");
        var $nextDiv = null;

        if ($activeDiv[0] === $(".hpFeature:last-child")[0]) {
            $nextDiv = $(".hpFeature:first-child");
        }
        else {
            $nextDiv = $activeDiv.next();
        }

        $activeDiv.removeClass("active");
        $nextDiv.addClass("active");
    });
});
```

If I'm understanding what you are trying to do correctly, this should get you the functionality that you are looking for.